# Ruby on Rails ActionMailer not sending email and not throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My ActionMailer has seemed to stop sending emails once the action has finished. I'm also not seeing any errors being thrown in Sidekiq or the Rails console while the worker is finished.

```
class OfferImportWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def perform(filename, user_email, current_user_id, original_filename)
    csv_file = csv_file(filename)

    num_imported_offers, errors = process_csv(csv_file, current_user_id, original_filename)
    WorkerMailer.offer_import_finished(user_email, num_imported_offers, errors).deliver!
  end
  ...
end
```

My worker mailer class

```
class WorkerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'email@email.com'

  def offer_import_finished(user_email, num_imported_offers, errors)
    @num_imported_offers = num_imported_offers
    @errors = errors
    mail(to: user_email, subject: 'CSV offers import has finished')
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

I've tried `deliver!`, `deliver_now`, and `deliver_now!` and none of them seem to produce a different result. Any clues as to how I can try down why the email isn't firing? Part of the worker is opening the mailer template in a new tab for the user + sending the email but I'm not seeing the second action being taken. I see `Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :csv_file` in the rails console whenever I finish a csv upload. Would this stop it from sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

To see what might be happening, I'd configure it to raise errors:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

Comment: yup just added this and saw `Unpermitted parameters:: csv_file`. Not sure how I would permit this though because it isn't an attribute on the Offers model but I `params[:csv_file]` being used in some import method on the `offers_controller`.